# pass an int iterator into a new Runnable defined within a for loop

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A final counter in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682942/a-final-counter-in-a-for-loop)

Below is the code I'm currently running. I'd like to be able to pass the iterator i into the new Runnable() code. I know I usually need the make variables final in order to pass into an inner class, but that ruins the effect of the iterator. I know normally I could try to make the Runnable inner class a true class (excuse my lack of terminology), but then I'd lose the effects of the CountDownLatches.

```
private long generateThreads(int cores){
    if (cores <= 0)
        cores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();

    System.out.println("Using " + cores + " threads for processing");

    final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
    final CountDownLatch ready = new CountDownLatch(cores);
    final CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
    final CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(cores);

    for (int i = 1; i <= cores; i++){
        exec.execute(new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                ready.countDown();
                try{
                    start.await();
                    //do work
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e){
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                } finally{
                    done.countDown();
                    exec.shutdown();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    long startTime = 0;
    try{
        ready.await();
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        start.countDown();
        done.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return System.nanoTime() - startTime;
}
```

Does anyone know of a way to give each thread the iterator, or create a class that shows all of the outer class members, particularly the CountDownLatches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just assign value of `i` to a final variable inside the loop.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= cores; i++){
    final int iFinal = i;

    exec.execute(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            ready.countDown();
            try{
                start.await();
                System.out.println( "i=" + iFinal );
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally{
                done.countDown();
                exec.shutdown();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: wow... i did a headdesk. Thank you very much. this is great and I feel foolish.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want the runnable to keep a "reference" to the iterator so that it can observe the increments. One way to do it which is thread safe is to use an `AtomicInteger`:

```
final AtomicInteger i = new AtomicInteger(1); 
for (; i.get() <= cores; i.incrementAndGet()){
    exec.execute(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            //you can access i here
            int j = i.get();
        }
    });
}
```

Note that this assumes that you only read `i` from the Runnables - if you also write it, the behaviour of the condition `i.get() <= cores` could be unexpected.

Comment: lol - we both missed the answer trying to be too complicated. see Alex's answer :)

Comment: @Bohemian I don't know - his answer and ours achieve different goals - I'm not sure whether the OP wants to see the counter change within the runnable or simply get the value at the time the runnable is created...

Comment: @Bohemian Looks like you are right! ;-)

Comment: yes, thank you. I voted you up as well, however I chose the other as I really just need the number as an offset later in the //do work section, and just using an int is nicer than creating a whole new object. both methods work in this case, but the other requires less memory consumption. Thank you again

Comment: @tophersmith116 If that's what you need then the other answer is better indeed.

Comment: In a last ditch attempt at a hat, is [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12981230/why-is-the-slave-machine-faster-for-reading-than-master-in-database-replication/14145769#14145769) awesome or what?

Comment: @Bohemian Sorry out of vote for the day! You are way ahead of everybody else anyway!

Comment: Actually, you could help me get a gold badge by voting for the other guy's accepted answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7281469/7285304#7285304)

Comment: @Bohemian Upvoted his and yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this trick:

```
final int[] holder = new int[1]; // the array is final, not its contents

for (int i = 1; i <= cores; i++){
    holder[0] = i;
    exec.execute(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            int i = holder[0]; // compiles
            ready.countDown();
            try{
                start.await();
                //do work
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e){
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            } finally{
                done.countDown();
                exec.shutdown();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The reason this compiles is that the array *reference* is `final`, but the *contents* of the array is able to be changed.

I'm not sure how useful this will be, because although I didn't read your code thoroughly, it doesn't seem threadsafe - the order of execution of threads is indeterminable, so your iterated value could be anything when the Runnable actually executes.

Comment: is `int i = holder[0]` thread safe? I am not sure that there is a visibility guarantee when doing that (even if the array is final).

Comment: @assylias It's not threadsafe, but neither is the design IMHO. This answer does answer the question though. (see edited answer)

Answer (score 0):

This kind of goes against your question but another solution is to work with some of Java's functional programming libraries.  I hate writing threads and these libraries let you simply write out the problem you're attempting to solve with higher-order logic and handles concurrency optimization behind the scenes.

Guava and lambdaJ are easy to work with.